# Which JavaScript library to use for dynamic process diagrams?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I want to visualize a process diagram like in this picture and I was wondering which JavaScript library (or Python library) I should use to do this. I want the diagram to be dynamic. For example, when a user clicks on the text box "Inclusief leiderschap", I'd like the diagram to transition and then show the next textbox "uitleg" which provides more information on that topic. I also want the diagram to shrink to fit a div/svg when more text boxes appear. I have already used d3.js in the past for making interactive graphs and I was wondering if this library would be useful in this case too.

[image: Process Diagram]